# How can I have two different endpoint with different namespace and same JAXB class?

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, jaxb

I am using spring soap ws.

I have following JAXB domain classes correspond to complex types

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "reference",
    "reason"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "request-message")
public class RequestMessageType {

    @XmlElement(name = "reference", required = true)
    protected String reference;
    @XmlElement(name = "reason")
    protected String reason;

   // I have getters and setters but removed here.
}
```

I have following class with @XmlRegistry annotations

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _RequestMessage_QNAME = new QName("http://namespace/url", "request-message");

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://namespace/url", name = "request-message")
    public JAXBElement<RequestMessageType> createDisconnectRequestMessage(RequestMessageType  value) {
        return new JAXBElement<RequestMessageType>(_RequestMessage_QNAME, RequestMessageType.class, null, value);
    }    
}
```

Following are endpoints

```
   @Endpoint
    public class FirstEndPoint {

        private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://first/url/version";

        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FirstEndPoint.class);

        @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "request-message")
        @ResponsePayload
        public JAXBElement<ResponseMessageType> requestMessage(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<RequestMessageType> requestMessage) {
            LOG.info("request-message : first version ID : " + requestMessage.getValue().getReference());
        //Preparing response and return response 
        }
    }

    @Endpoint
    public class SecondEndPoint {

        private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://second/url/version";
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SecondEndPoint.class);


        @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "request-message")
        @ResponsePayload
        public JAXBElement<ResponseMessageType> requestMessage(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<RequestMessageType> requestMessage) {
            LOG.info("request-message : second version ID : " + requestMessage.getValue().getReference());
         //Preparing response and return response 

        }
    }
```

When I make Soap request, I am using NAMESPACE_URI given in endpoints in soap request.

Here, in this case, I am getting following response

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">unexpected element (uri:"http://first/url/version", local:"request-message"). Expected elements are &lt;{http://namespace/url}request-message&gt;</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I use "http://namespace/url" as NAMESPACE_URI in endpoint and in soap request I am getting the proper response but I try to make it different for two endpoints with two different namespaces then it is not working and gives above response.

How can I use two different namespaces for two different endpoints with same JAXB class? I am completely new to spring and web service.

Additional info : RequestMessageType class and ObjectFactory class are in one package and in package-info.java namespace is

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace="http://namespace/url",elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.example
```

Do I need to change anything in package-info.java file ?

Comment: I would be good to see also your generated WSDL
In any case in my schemas I'd define two request and response elements. These elements would be of the same type. When I have time if you want I may share a simple project on my github account

Comment: I would recommend make a RequestMessageType abstract, and make 2  classes to extend from it.  Those classes register seprately. By doing so: your wsdls would have different namespaces, but your service layer can be kept unmodified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a sample project. I hope it can be useful to you. You can give a look at it here: https://github.com/angeloimm/spring-ws-sample
Basically this is my WSDL file (in SOAP Web Service all is ruled by WSDL):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:ss="http://www.example.org/SpringSample/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="SpringSample"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/SpringSample/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/SpringSample/">
            <xsd:complexType name="abstractRequest">
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:element name="reqName" type="xsd:string" nillable="false"
                        maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="abstractResponse">
                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:element name="responseName" type="xsd:string"
                        nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:element name="requestImplementation" type="ss:abstractRequest" />
            <xsd:element name="responseImplementation" type="ss:abstractResponse" />
            <xsd:element name="requestImplementation2" type="ss:abstractRequest" />
            <xsd:element name="responseImplementation2" type="ss:abstractResponse" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="OperationRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="ss:requestImplementation" name="request" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="OperationResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="ss:responseImplementation" name="response" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="OperationRequest2">
        <wsdl:part element="ss:requestImplementation2" name="request2" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="OperationResponse2">
        <wsdl:part element="ss:responseImplementation2" name="response2" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="SpringSample">
        <wsdl:operation name="Operation1">
            <wsdl:input message="ss:OperationRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="ss:OperationResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="Operation2">
            <wsdl:input message="ss:OperationRequest2" />
            <wsdl:output message="ss:OperationResponse2" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="SpringSampleSOAP" type="ss:SpringSample">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="Operation1">
            <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://www.example.org/SpringSample/Operation1" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="Operation2">
            <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://www.example.org/SpringSample/Operation2" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding> 
    <wsdl:service name="SpringSample">
        <wsdl:port binding="ss:SpringSampleSOAP" name="SpringSampleSOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://www.example.org/" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

As you can see I defined 2 complex type: `abstractRequest` and `abstractResponse`. Then I *implemented* them by using the elements `requestImplementation`,`requestImplementation2`,`responseImplementation`,`responseImplementation2` According to WS-I specification you need to use separate operations and elements

Then I wrote this endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class SampleEndpoint
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleEndpoint.class.getName());
    private static final String NAME_SPACE_URI = "http://www.example.org/SpringSample/";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAME_SPACE_URI, localPart="requestImplementation")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<AbstractResponse> operationOneResp(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<AbstractRequest> ar)
    {
        if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
        {
            logger.debug("Operation 1 request "+ar.getValue().getReqName());
        }
        ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
        AbstractResponse aResp = of.createAbstractResponse();
        aResp.setResponseName("operation 1 response");
        JAXBElement<AbstractResponse> result = of.createResponseImplementation(aResp);
        return result;
    }
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAME_SPACE_URI, localPart="requestImplementation2")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<AbstractResponse> operationTwoResp(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<AbstractRequest> ar)
    {
        if( logger.isDebugEnabled() )
        {
            logger.debug("Operation 2 request "+ar.getValue().getReqName());
        }
        ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
        AbstractResponse aResp = of.createAbstractResponse();
        aResp.setResponseName("operation 2 response");
        JAXBElement<AbstractResponse> result = of.createResponseImplementation(aResp);
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see now I always use `AbstractRequest` and `AbstractResponse` JAXBElement in both methods. The 2 methods can also be in 2 different endpoints

I hope it's what you needed and it's useful

Angelo