# Different JAXB Namespace for same XmlRootElement in one package?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have one class annotated with `@XmlRootElement` and there is one `package-info.jav`a file with one namespace. Can I have multiple namespaces for this same class annotated with `@XMLRootElement`? I can't find an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following classes as example (annotated by `@XmlRootElement`) in the same package to override the namespace.

---

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root" ,namespace = "com.foo")
public class Foo{
       ...
}
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root" ,namespace = "com.bar")
public class Bar{
       ...
}
```

---

- [Example 1](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html)
- [Example 2](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html)

Comment: It is two different namespace for two different XML root element foo and bar but I want two different namespaces for one XML root element let say only for Foo.

Comment: You can't do this using a single class. You have to create another class and use also `name` attribute on `@XmlRootElement(name = "Bar" , namespace = "com.bar")`

Comment: my main issue is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583409/how-can-i-have-two-different-endpoint-with-different-namespace-and-same-jaxb-cla . it will be more clear what I want.

Comment: why are you open another "question" ? ... Anyway, you need a hierarchy there using an `abstract` father..